# Why does this JS link require 2 clicks to trigger?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a script which will go along with my already in place website. Basically, when you click the `Show/Hide button`, it shows an overlay over the content `div`. Then there's an option to hide the entire `div`, both overlay, content, and container.

Problem is, you have to click the `hide` link twice for it to hide all the divs.

I have a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/8c3VZ/3/

**EDIT: I updated the jsFiddle with the correct version of the JS. I had the incomplete one in there before.**

Also, there's more to the script that allows cookies, I just didn't include it to reduce the amount of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `toggle_visibility()` code to this to let jQuery's `.toggle()` and `.css()` do most of the work for you:

```
<script>
    function toggle_visibility(a) {
        var item = $("#" + a);
        item.toggle();
        $.cookie("disp" + a, item.css("display"));
    }
</script>
```

The reason it wasn't working is that `b.style.display` in your original code only returns inline styles.  It does not return styles set by CSS rules.  If you really wanted to get that style, you could use jQuery's `.css("display")` method.  But, in this case, you can just use `.toggle()` and let that do all the work for you.

Comment: What about the cookie function (sorry for adding this part in late, I had the wrong js code in the fiddle)?

Comment: I added the cookie part to my answer.  You can just get the resulting display value after the toggle and set that into the cookie.

Comment: I like this solution as it reduces the amount of code (and updates it from what I had). As for the cookie part, works fine.

Answer (score 7):

It's because the style.display attribute is undefined at first.  reversing the logic can fix this.  Basically the reason why is because element.style.display directly reads the style attribute of the element and not a javascript attribute like in this element:

```
<div style="display:none;">blah</div>
```

because your element doesn't have the style attribute at first, it defaults to the else.  Switching the logic will default it to hiding it rather than showing it.

http://jsfiddle.net/MpJDN/

```
function toggle_visibility(a) {
var b = document.getElementById(a);
if (b.style.display == "none") {
    b.style.display = "block";
}
else {
    b.style.display = "none";
}
}
```

Comment: I updated my question. I forgot to add in the part where the script handles cookies. Can your code be updated to work with the cookie part? Other than that, thank you for the explanation as to why it didn't work.

Comment: @Charlie not sure.  It looks like your cookie syntax is wrong :S it keeps throwing a `has no method 'cookie'` error. I'll have to look at it more when I get home.

Comment: @Joseph - $.cookie is a jQuery plug-in, not part of the standard jQuery so you need to add that plug-in to your project.

Comment: The rest of the script is in a separate file, I just didn't include it so that the code would be smaller.